# Consumer Loan Payoff Interest vs Principal

Tags: personal-loan

I have a consumer loan, and need to know if I can pay off the principal or interest early.  If so, which would be best? Also, how would I find out the pr amount balance?

Comment: You need to add more details, what country is this in, who is the lender, etc...

Comment: If you've got the choice, paying off the principal saves future interest, but paying interest early probably won't save anything.

Comment: You find out the current balance by calling your lender, or checking their website.

Answer (score 2):

It best to pay the principal early, because then there's less loan left to accrue interest on.

Whether you **can** make early principal payments depends on the loan contract, and your state & national laws on such things.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in most consumer loans, the interest is computed based on the principal at every statement period. So there's not a benefit to paying "extra" interest since it's re-calculated every period from the principal amount. If you pay down the principal, the amount of interest that is charged will be lower, and so the total balance paid is smaller and you'll pay the loan off early (all else being equal).

There are some loans where the interest is *pre-computed* and reflected in a total balance that is owed regardless of when you pay it off. In those cases, you can pay either since it doesn't affect the total amount that you owe.

> how would I find out the [principal] amount balance?

It should be shown on your loan statement. You can also contact the loan servicer or visit their web site to fine the balance. They might also give you a "payoff" balance that will show how much interest has accrued to date that you will need to pay as well. This is more common of larger loans like mortgages and car loans where interest accrues daily.